# Yii2: Model column alias

Tags: yii2

I have some silly column names in my database, is there an easy way to alias a column name so it's always used for example:

```
public function columnAlias(){
    return ['id'=>'ID', 'foo'=>'Bar'];
}

$model->id === $model->ID
$model->foo === $model->Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for accessing the attributes on the model you can write a `get` function.

So adding:

```
public function getId() {
    return $this->ID;
}

public function getFoo() {
    return $this->Bar;
}
```

will enable you to access ID and Bar like

```
$model->id;
$model->foo;
```

This works because of Yii2's use of the magic method `__get`: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Component.php#L134

Comment: Good idea, Ill use get set to do it. I was wondering if there was a buit in function I was not aware of.